# Simple progress indicator that shows the user how much % of the site he has visited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I want to create a competition where the user has to visit every page on my site.

- On the top of the site I want to display progress
- Progress is shown in % "You have explored XX% of my site."
- When progress is 100% he is redirected to a page I can define
- My site is small (10 pages)

I'd like to do this in Javascript/JQuery.

Does anyone have an idea how i can best accomplish this?
It might be that my site will expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [jquery UI Progressbar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar)

for example if they viewed 75% of the site:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 75 });
```

**UPDATE**

The '75' would come from the server side and be displayed to the user. Dont use JS to decide how much of the page a user has gone thru, do that on the server side.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer! That gave me a nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Although you can do the UI part using JS/jQuery, **do not** use client-side storage (eg: cookies).

Instead, use sessions, or some form of server-side storage.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store the information about which pages were visited before. Personally I would use a server-side solution for that (session or database) but if you want to do it client-side you would have to use something like cookies or local data storage.

For a client-side solution, you can use a combination of [html5 local data storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) for browsers that support it and cookies for the rest.